# Laravel generating views with wrong user root instead of www-data

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5

I don't know why Laravel (in Ubuntu 14.04 server with Apache) is now generating the views in /storage/framework/views with "-rw-r--r-- root root" instead of "-rwxr-xr-x www-data www-data" like before.

And that is making troubles for me when I try to open that new view, and throws me a 500 error.

How can I change this to how it was before?

Comment: To help clarify specific terms: `-rw-r--r--` is called "file permissions" or just "permissions", `root root` is called "file ownership" or just "ownership".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the group of the whole Laravel folder to www-data.

Command: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data laravel_root/`

Also check on your server configuration whether it's running as `root` or `www-data`group.

Comment: And how can I check if the server is running as root or www-data?

Comment: go to the root folder and run `ls -la`